# File cart (document basket) – good UI examples

Tags: website-design

can anyone provide a website with a good example of a well designed **file cart**?
I've researched the topic but there's plenty of articles about shopping carts and not file carts. The only examples of file carts I've found were the simple ones which allowed the users to **share files via email or merge files**.
However I struggle to find a case which would have more elaborate functionalities, like e.g. ability to create a submittal based on contents in file cart, which would require **ability to sort and order assets** and **adding customizable cover page** (e.g. adding a project title).
One more question:

1. Would it be beneficial to ensure that merged .pdf file size gets optimized before a user downloads it (should the user have a choice to download the original or optimized size)?

Any feedback will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kasia-spy, what is a file cart? Answers will depend on what you want your users to do with it. On a first glance you could use a list component for the files with a cover image on the left.
Regarding your pdf optimization question: This depends if the users are interested in the original file.

Comment: When users browse a web, they can add various documents to the file cart (these are mostly product data sheets and other technical documents). We have a use case that e.g. architects later on merge such files and add a front cover page to submit such a technical documentation for a project. We were hoping that we could offer them such a functionality in our file cart in which they can already merge files and share them via email but there's no option to add a customizable cover page or sort and order assets after they are added to the file cart. I'd like to see examples of such file carts.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you are missing one most famous File Cart: Google Drive.

[image: Google Drive]

Have a look for that, you might have all the answers you need.

About, compression question, I think user's discretion is must. Compression may compromise with quality of the document.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.